# Strange event with socket.io connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io

socket make infinity requests with log:

> XHR finished loading: GET "".

Node application breaks down.

I wanna startup old project but can't.

I update node to the last version , host is centos 6 .
I update also socket.io

with npm but I don't have the json package ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.IO doesn't exclusively use Web Sockets.  It can use a number of transports, including long-polling AJAX.  That's what you're seeing, and it is completely normal.

As for why your application is breaking... who knows, there isn't enough information here to answer your question.  If you want to run an old project, try an old version of Node.js.  Since you don't have an old package.json, you'll have to guess as to the versions of the required packages around that time.

Comment: I still need to check with updated version of "socket.io client" packages. I don't see reason why not to update node-modules. it is not too much complicated  project.

Comment: @NikolaLukic If you're going to make an effort to actually update everything, why post a question about how to get by without updating everything?

Comment: This app works fine in the past. I just want it to update. I need to check client side also i will post when i figure what it is.